# How to slide image of adobe After effect?

Tags: adobe

I had created images in horizontal by using adobe after effect, but it is motion that it auto slide per image in few seconds. I want it to be able to slide manually when i place this at android studio. is it correct to use adobe AE? please recommend which software is appropriate for this purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After effects usually exports media as videos...
It's not a good idea to use Adobe ae. As you want to control slides manually in Android studio

Comment: could you please recommend which software is better for this?

Comment: you might need to use js scripting (java)